# How can I transform the string in excel

Tags: excel

I'm looking for a way to transform a string like 'TRSP_INV_CD' to 'TrspInvCd' in excel.
I will be very grateful if anyone can give me a solution to this issue. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`PROPER`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/proper-function-52a5a283-e8b2-49be-8506-b2887b889f94?ns=excel&version=90&syslcid=1033&uilcid=1033&appver=zxl900&helpid=xlmain11.chm60162&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) to capitalise, and [`SUBSTITUTE`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/substitute-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332?ns=excel&version=90&syslcid=1033&uilcid=1033&appver=zxl900&helpid=xlmain11.chm60168&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) to remove the `_`'s

`=SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(A1),"_","")`

Answer (score 1):

Try below formula

```
=SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_"," "))," ","")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways towards the solution of this problem :

1. Using the replace function (built-in)
2. Using substitute formula
   Example: =SUBSTITUTE(ORIGINAL_STRING,"OLD_CHARACTER","NEW_CHARACTER")
   In this case  =SUBSTITUTE(TRSP_INV_CD,"_","")

For more information on this consider visiting this [here](https://spreadsheetplanet.com/remove-specific-character-from-string-excel/)